# How to Speed Up Piecewise Symbolic Integration

Tags: performance-tuning, piecewise

In Mathematica, I am attempting to integrate over 2-D $\phi$ "hat functions" for a FEM scheme. I suppose I am only observing "interior points" in the domain $\left( 0 , 2 \right) \times \left( 0 , 10 \right)$. I formulated the function and tested that it does exactly what I want. I then setup the integrals, but the issue is I can by hand solve these integrals faster than the time Mathematica is taking. Below is the code I'm using (substituted greek letters for easier reading):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
phi[i_, j_, h_, tau_, x_, t_] = Piecewise[{
    {1 - (x - h*i)/h - (t - tau*j)/tau, 
     And[x >= h*i, t >= tau*j, t - tau*(j + 1) <= -(tau/h)*(x - h*i)]},
    {1 - (x - h*i)/h, 
     And[x <= h*(i + 1), t <= tau*j, t - tau*j >= -(tau/h)*(x - h*i)]},
    {1 + (t - tau*j)/tau, 
     And[x >= h*i, t >= tau*(j - 1), t - tau*j <= -(tau/h)*(x - h*i)]},
    {1 + (x - h*i)/h + (t - tau*j)/tau, 
     And[x <= h*i, t <= tau*j, t - tau*j >= -(tau/h)*(x - h*(i - 1))]},
    {1 + (x - h*i)/h, 
     And[x >= h*(i - 1), t >= tau*j, 
      t - tau*(j + 1) <= -(tau/h)*(x - h*(i - 1))]},
    {1 - (t - tau*j)/tau, 
     And[x <= h*i, t <= tau*(j + 1), 
      t - tau*(j + 1) >= -(tau/h)*(x - h*(i - 1))]}
    (*0 ELSE*)
    }];
phix[i_, j_, h_, tau_, x_, t_] = D[phi[i, j, h, tau, x, t], {x, 1}];

Integrate[
 Integrate[
  phix[i, j, h, tau, x, t]*phix[i, j, h, tau, x, t], {x, 0, 2},
  Assumptions -> 
   i \[Element] Integers && 1 < i < 2/h && j \[Element] Integers && 
    1 < j < 10/tau && h \[Element] Reals && 0 < h && 
    tau \[Element] Reals && 0 < tau], {t, 0, 10},
 Assumptions -> 
  i \[Element] Integers && 1 < i < 2/h && j \[Element] Integers && 
   1 < j < 10/tau && h \[Element] Reals && 0 < h && 
   tau \[Element] Reals && 0 < tau]
```

For some background, $i$ and $j$ are "interior indices" and so for some $m$ and $n$ we have $h=\frac{2}{m}$ and $\tau = \frac{10}{n}$ in which I require $1<i<m$ and $1<j<n$. $h$ and $\tau$ are positive reals that go down to $0$.

If I require an abstract answer, one in terms of symbolic $h$ and $\tau$, how can I speed up the integral's evaluation without having to separate the integral into individual regions?

Answer (score 2):

Right as I clicked "Review Question", I found a trick that sped things up significantly, and will leave as an answer. Further optimization is still requested.

By realizing $\phi _{i , j} \times \phi _{i , j}$ is only non-zero within an "almost square" domain locally in terms of $i$ and $j$ (including derivatives), we can shrink the domain of integration - using Mathematica code `{x, (i-1)*h, (i+1)*h}` and `{t, (j-1)*tau, (j+1)*tau}` as the new bounds are equivalent to integrating over the entire domain. I can only assume this somehow significantly reduces operations. This yields the much faster code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
phi[i_, j_, h_, tau_, x_, t_] = Piecewise[{
    {1 - (x - h*i)/h - (t - tau*j)/tau, 
     And[x >= h*i, t >= tau*j, t - tau*(j + 1) <= -(tau/h)*(x - h*i)]},
    {1 - (x - h*i)/h, 
     And[x <= h*(i + 1), t <= tau*j, t - tau*j >= -(tau/h)*(x - h*i)]},
    {1 + (t - tau*j)/tau, 
     And[x >= h*i, t >= tau*(j - 1), t - tau*j <= -(tau/h)*(x - h*i)]},
    {1 + (x - h*i)/h + (t - tau*j)/tau, 
     And[x <= h*i, t <= tau*j, t - tau*j >= -(tau/h)*(x - h*(i - 1))]},
    {1 + (x - h*i)/h, 
     And[x >= h*(i - 1), t >= tau*j, 
      t - tau*(j + 1) <= -(tau/h)*(x - h*(i - 1))]},
    {1 - (t - tau*j)/tau, 
     And[x <= h*i, t <= tau*(j + 1), 
      t - tau*(j + 1) >= -(tau/h)*(x - h*(i - 1))]}
    (*0 ELSE*)
    }];
phix[i_, j_, h_, tau_, x_, t_] = D[phi[i, j, h, tau, x, t], {x, 1}];

Integrate[
 Integrate[
  phix[i, j, h, tau, x, t]*
   phix[i, j, h, tau, x, t], {x, (i - 1)*h, (i + 1)*h},
  Assumptions -> 
   i \[Element] Integers && 1 < i < 2/h && j \[Element] Integers && 
    1 < j < 10/tau && h \[Element] Reals && 0 < h && 
    tau \[Element] Reals && 0 < tau], {t, (j - 1)*tau, (j + 1)*tau},
 Assumptions -> 
  i \[Element] Integers && 1 < i < 2/h && j \[Element] Integers && 
   1 < j < 10/tau && h \[Element] Reals && 0 < h && 
   tau \[Element] Reals && 0 < tau]
```

This new code requires the assumptions to prove the bounds of integration are real.

Expanding the code to all the other "interpolant coefficients", or integrating $\phi _{i , j} \times \phi _{\alpha , \beta}$ for $\left( i , j \right) \neq \left( \alpha , \beta \right)$, the same bounds can be used by the support of these $\phi$ functions, and so only a modification to the integrand is required.